# Setting up AEM6.3 as a service Linux Redhat version 7.3

Tags: aem, redhat, systemd

I am trying to set up **AEM6.3** environment as a **service** and following below steps. But having some issues-

I have **RedHat version 7.3 linux server.**

I am taking reference from [here](https://blogs.perficient.com/adobe/2016/06/17/start-aem-automatically-using-systemd)

1. **aem file**- (**/usr/bin/aem**)

   ## !/bin/bash

   ```
   #
   # /etc/rc.d/init.d/aem6
   #
   #
   # # of the file to the end of the tags section must begin with a #
   # character. After the tags section, there should be a blank line.
   # This keeps normal comments in the rest of the file from being
   # mistaken for tags, should they happen to fit the pattern.>
   #
   # chkconfig: 35 85 15
   # description: This service manages the Adobe Experience Manager java process.
   # processname: aem6
   # pidfile: /crx-quickstart/conf/cq.pid

   # Source function library.
   . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

   SCRIPT_NAME=`basename $0`
   AEM_ROOT=/mnt/crx/author
   AEM_USER=root

   ########
   BIN=${AEM_ROOT}/crx-quickstart/bin
   START=${BIN}/start
   STOP=${BIN}/stop
   STATUS="${BIN}/status"

   case "$1" in
   start)
   echo -n "Starting AEM services: "
   su - ${AEM_USER} ${START}
   touch /var/lock/subsys/$SCRIPT_NAME
   ;;
   stop)
   echo -n "Shutting down AEM services: "
   su - ${AEM_USER} ${STOP}
   rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$SCRIPT_NAME
   ;;
   status)
   su - ${AEM_USER} ${STATUS}
   ;;
   restart)
   su - ${AEM_USER} ${STOP}
   su - ${AEM_USER} ${START}
   ;;
   reload)
   ;;
   *)
   echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|status|reload}"
   exit 1
   ;;
   esac
   ```
2. **aem.system (/etc/systemd/system**) (Couldn't find **system.d** so placed this file **systemd**)

   [Unit]
       Description=Adobe Experience Manager

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/aem start
   ExecStop=/usr/bin/aem stop
   ExecReload=/usr/bin/aem restart
   RemainAfterExit=yes

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. I have provided permissions to both of these files as-

   ```
   #chmod u+rwx /usr/bin/aem
   #chmod u+rwx /etc/systemd/system/aem.system
   ```
4. When I am giving these commands-

   ```
   #cd /etc/systemd/system
   #systemctl enable aem.system
   ```

It's giving me below error-

```
    #systemctl enable aem.system

    **Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory**
```

Am I missing any step here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in placing the custom unit file in `/etc/systemd/system` as that is the place for all unpackages files. However, your file should really be called `aem.service`. To the best of my knowledge, systemd does not pick up files ending in `.system`. On a side note: Those overly liberal filesystem permissions really are unnecessary, 755 should be more than sufficient.

Also: If there really is a `/etc/init.d/aem6` file as the linked guide suggests, systemd's SysV-compatibility layer should be able to read that one in and `systemctl enable --now aem6` is everything you need to do.